# Access XML file in a Zipped Resource C#

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have an XML file that is contained in a zip folder that's been embedded into a project resource folder. I am trying to figure out to access the XML content without using 3rd party software. I have seen the use of SharpZip to do stream the contents, but I am trying to avoid 3rd party software.

Comment: If you want to avoid using existing software, you'll need to rewrite all of that code yourself.  Good luck with that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive

Comment: System.IO.Compression